# How to use eles.components() to filter direct neighbours of one node?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to filter all nodes not further away then one edge of a given node. I dont have a compound graph. I tried

```
var children = cy.$('#1').components()
```

But this only returns the node #1. I also tried

```
var allEles = cy.elements()
var myChildren = allEles.componentsOf(cy.$('#1'))
```

But this seems to return all nodes again. The docs also state a selector syntax "> (child selector) Matches direct children of the parent node (e.g. node > node)." But I cant figure that one out either. I tried

```
var myChildren = cy.elements('node#1 > node')
```

getting an empty array.

So, how can filter for direct children (depth=1) of a given node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try use:

```
// outgoers return all elements (edges as well) comming out from $('#1') 
// nodes() > select only nodes
var children = cy.$('#1').outgoers().nodes();
```

doc: https://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.outgoers

Comment: At first it also did not work, but you got me thinking. I went back to my source data and figured that defining `source` and `target` in the edges is not as trivial as I thought ;-) Now it works of course.